# How to force Windows to use cleartype for all font sizes

Tags: fonts, rendering, cleartype

I have some large Excel spreadsheets and often have to zoom out to have an overall view of them. However as I zoomed out, the characters are rendered in a smaller font, and until some point size it becomes aliased and pixelated. This can also be observed by resizing text to make it smaller. Typically at 8pt or less the characters won't be rendered with [ClearType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/cleartype/)

How can I have Windows font renderer to use ClearType at all font sizes?